# i heard a loud whistling/squeeling noise coming from the front tires of my 2004 subaru outback AWD.

Tags: subaru

I have never heard this sound before, it made the sound whether i used my brakes or not, it only stopped when i turned right. anyone have any idea what this could be?

Comment: Does the noise change when you use your brakes (in pitch or timber)?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please let us know as many details as possible about your situation.  This will help us give the best answer *and* will leave a trail of breadcrumbs for the next person who has the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had a situation like this many years ago: my 87 Mustang would make squeaking brake disk noises from one of the front wheels when the wheels were very close to straight ahead.  When I turned the steering wheel, the noise would sometimes stop.  This was eventually diagnosed as a brake disk that was very slightly warped.

Your car is getting older now (full disclosure: my car is the same age) so I'd be thinking about at the disks and the calipers.  If you can tell which side it's happening on, that would be a good start.  Things you could check:

1. Warped rotors (which could cause the brake pad to contact the rotor even with your foot off the pedal).
2. Brake caliper not opening all the way (same problem: the pad could still be touching ever so slightly).
3. Foreign material (e.g., something got between the pad and the rotor).

Comment: Yep - I had a piece of grit stuck between a rotor and pad. It sounded terrible but was only a couple of millimetres across.

Answer (score 0):

Worn pads. Pads worn down to the metal would cause your symptoms. Have your vehicle checked over for this noise, but expect to have the pads and rotors changed.